# Working the same Android Studio project from different workstations

Tags: android, project

How can I work an Android studio project from work and later at home without having configuration issues, shall I use something like dropbox ?

Answer (score 1):

You will be delighted to know that there wont be any configuration issues at all.
**Android Studio Projects** ar *portable*.

You just have to Copy the project from office. Bring it at home. And import it in your Android Studio by clicking **Import existing android studio project**. 1st time it will show an error message, mentioning that the sdk directory didn't matched. But don't worry, clicking **OK** button will solve the issue it self.

Just make sure your **sdk manager** is up to date in both machine of home and office.